# JSP in Folder inside webcontent unable to access servlet

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml, web-content

Pages folder inside the WebContent is unable to access CreateNewCampaign servlet inside the package. but I properly mapped in web.xml .but it shows error HTTP404 not found in localhost. I attached web.xml . may be some problem in the URL pattern.[error not found 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4hKe.png)
.

[tables.jsp unable to access servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJQ7b.png)

Comment: The URL is wrong; it’s mapped to `/CreateNewCampaign` but you’re trying to access it via `/pages/CreateNewCampaign`. Perhaps your JSP isn’t using an absolute path. Questions should stand on their own: include the server name/mapping and the JSP in question as code in the question rather than as links to pictures of code. And probably best not to map the same server twice.